# Python number increment

Tags: python

I am experimenting with python, and I've made this little math game. Though I am having some issue with a scoring system. Each time the player gets an answer correct, I want the score to increment by 1. I have tried, however I haven't got it to increase each time the player gets something right.
Heres the code

```
import operator
import random

operations = {
    "addition": ("+", operator.add),
    "substraction": ("-", operator.sub),
    "multiplication": ("*", operator.mul),
    "division": ("/", operator.floordiv),
}

def ask_operation(difficulty, maxtries=3):
    maxvalue = 5 * difficulty
    x = random.randint(1, maxvalue)
    y = random.randint(1, maxvalue)
    op_name, (op_symbol, op_fun) = random.choice(list(operations.items()))
    result = op_fun(x, y)
    score = 0

    print("Difficulty level %d" % difficulty)
    print("Now lets do a %s calculation and see how clever you are." % op_name)
    print("So what is %d %s %d?" % (x, op_symbol, y))

    for ntry in range(1, 1+maxtries):
        answer = int(input(">"))
        if answer == result:
            print("Correct!") 
            score += 1
            print score
            return True

        elif ntry == maxtries:
            print("That's %s incorrect answers.  The end." % maxtries)
        else:
            print("That's not right.  Try again.")
    return False

def play(difficulty):
    while ask_operation(difficulty):
        difficulty += 1
    print("Difficulty level achieved: %d" % difficulty)

play(1)
```

Comment: Is your indentation correct throughout the post?

Comment: No its not. I copied and pasted it from a textedit so I lost the formatting. I'll edit it

Comment: yeah fix the indentation please. At the moment, it looks like you set the score to 0 with every new question :/

Comment: `//Increment score//` is not a comment in Python

Answer (score 2):

The score is reset to 0 every time in `ask_operation`. You should initialize it in `play` instead.

By the way, `//Increment score//` is not valid Python. You can set comments in Python like this, even in Stack Overflow.

```
score += 1 # Increment score
```

Comment: Ah yes, sorry I sometimes get my syntax mixed up. Thanks, how would I initialise it in the play function? Sorry, I am very new to python.

Comment: The same way you did in `ask_operation`. Make sure you keep it before the while loop so it only runs once.